# How to remove class when pressing anywhere in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the header of the app I'm designing I have 4 buttons like this:

```
<li ng-click="visible = 1" class="dropdown">
    ....
    <ul ng-class="{'visible': visible==1}" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
    ....
</li>
```

I will make the `ul` visible when user click on an icon (which is the `li` element). I need to hide the `ul` when the user press anywhere else in the page.

I tried to set `visible=0` on `<body ng-click="visible = 0">` but it does not work. How can I set that event?

Comment: Well this visible has to be a css class style. And in it you have to tell it to hide the element.

Comment: yes, but it is not removing the class when pressing on the body

Comment: Did you try testing your click event? try outputing some some message in a console.log() when clicking the body. Does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does not work. I read the event must be on the document, and not in the body, since there are another elements in the body. But I don't know how to set the event on the document instead of body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long searching I could make this directive

```
app.directive("outsideClick", ['$document','$parse', function( $document, $parse ){
    return {
        link: function( $scope, $element, $attributes ){
            var scopeExpression = $attributes.outsideClick,
                onDocumentClick = function(event){
                    var isChild = $element[0].contains(event.target);

                    if(!isChild) {
                        $scope.$apply(scopeExpression);
                    }
                };

            $document.on("click", onDocumentClick);

            $element.on('$destroy', function() {
                $document.off("click", onDocumentClick);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then just add the `outside-click="closeMenu()"` in the ul, and

```
$scope.closeMenu = function(){
    $scope.visible = 0;
}
```

set the variable to 0, in the controller, to hide the menu dropdown.